# Why is link is being displayed on the next line instead of the same?

Tags: html, css

I have this html below:

```css
    body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
    }
    
    .primary {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    
    .upcoming-events {
        border: 1px solid #E7EAEC;
        background-color: #FFF;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .upcoming-events-header {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #E7EAEC;
        padding: 20px 10px;
        color: #2F343B;
    }
    
    .upcoming-events-header-text {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .upcoming-count {
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    .event {
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .event-date-container {
        height: 65px;
        border-right: 1px solid #CFD4D9;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 65px;
    }
    
    .day-label {
        width: 100%;
        color: #00A1A1;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Interstate', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Sans-Serif';
        letter-spacing: -0.2px;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: 700;
    }
    
    .date-label {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 11px;
        display: block;
        letter-spacing: -0.1px;
        color: #87909A;
        width: 100%;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        margin-top: 2px;
        line-height: 14px;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .event-info-container {
        
    }
    
    a {
        color: #085F99;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
        <section class="primary">
            <div class="upcoming-events">
                <div class="upcoming-events-header">
                    <div class="upcoming-events-header-text">
                        <span class="upcoming-count">95</span>
                        Games
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="upcoming-events-body">
                    <div class="event">
                        <div class="event-date-container">
                            <span class="day-label">FRI</span>
                            <span class="date-label">July 25</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="event-info-container">
                            <a>Pittsburgh Pirates</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

The problem is the `Pittsburgh Pirates` link is not appearing to the right but at the bottom as shown in the picture below:

[image]

Can someone tell me how to move the `Pittsburgh Pirates` to the right (basically right after that vertical border)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't make your `.event-info-container` a table-cell, like `event-date-container` before it.

Use this CSS for it to get the desired display::

```
.event-info-container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 20px;
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.primary {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.upcoming-events {
  border: 1px solid #E7EAEC;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.upcoming-events-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E7EAEC;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  color: #2F343B;
}

.upcoming-events-header-text {
  display: block;
}

.upcoming-count {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.event {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.event-date-container {
  height: 65px;
  border-right: 1px solid #CFD4D9;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 65px;
}

.day-label {
  width: 100%;
  color: #00A1A1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Interstate', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Sans-Serif';
  letter-spacing: -0.2px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.date-label {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
  color: #87909A;
  width: 100%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 2px;
  line-height: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.event-info-container {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

a {
  color: #085F99;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="primary">
  <div class="upcoming-events">
    <div class="upcoming-events-header">
      <div class="upcoming-events-header-text">
        <span class="upcoming-count">95</span> Games
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="upcoming-events-body">
      <div class="event">
        <div class="event-date-container">
          <span class="day-label">FRI</span>
          <span class="date-label">July 25</span>
        </div>
        <div class="event-info-container">
          <a>Pittsburgh Pirates</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This answer fit in more with what was missing within the html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following to your css file. This is something you can easily find from other posts to be honest..

```
.event div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://codepen.io/julysfx/pen/proBOq

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex` on the container.

```css
body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,"Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
}
    
.primary {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
    
.upcoming-events {
    border: 1px solid #E7EAEC;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
    
.upcoming-events-header {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E7EAEC;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    color: #2F343B;
}
    
.upcoming-events-header-text {
    display: block;
}
    
.upcoming-count {
    font-weight: 700;
}
    
.event {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
}
    
.event-date-container {
    height: 65px;
    border-right: 1px solid #CFD4D9;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 65px;
}
    
.day-label {
    width: 100%;
    color: #00A1A1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    font-family: 'Interstate', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', 'Sans-Serif';
    letter-spacing: -0.2px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 700;
}
    
.date-label {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: -0.1px;
    color: #87909A;
    width: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 2px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
    
.event-info-container {
    padding: 22px;
}
    
a {
    color: #085F99;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="primary">
  <div class="upcoming-events">
    <div class="upcoming-events-header">
      <div class="upcoming-events-header-text">
        <span class="upcoming-count">95</span>
                        Games
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="upcoming-events-body">
      <div class="event">
        <div class="event-date-container">
          <span class="day-label">FRI</span>
          <span class="date-label">July 25</span>
        </div>
        <div class="event-info-container">
          <a>Pittsburgh Pirates</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```